# is it possible to have React Native and Android Views in Same activity/android fragment layout?

Tags: android, react-native

Suppose I have my page that is completely written in React Native that has views linearly added. For example A - B- c -D. Now I need to add view E that is actually a Android Fragment(abc.xml layout file). So my view Hierachy should be A(RN) - B(RN) - E(Android fragment) - C(RN) - D(RN). is this possible?

Comment: what "written in Android" means?

Comment: My mistake...I want to say layout are written in Android code just like we can write in react native. For example we write xml files in layout folder in Android studio for Android.

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android.html